# if 13* D = 1 mod 60 then D = 37 how?

Tags: math, rsa, modulo

I am solving an example problem, [RSA algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(algorithm))
I have been given two prime numbers 7 and 11. Let's say `p=7` and `q=11`
I have to calculate the decryption key, `d`, for some encryption key, `e`.

Firstly I calculated `n=p*q` which implies that `n=77`.

Suppose that **`e=13`**,
to calculate `d` I used the formula `d*e = 1 mod fi`,
where `fi=(p-1)(q-1)`, and so `fi=60`

The final equation becomes `13*d = 1 mod fi`

According to some solved example
`d` is calculated to be 37, how is this result obtained?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruence_theorem . When the modulus is small (e.g. uint32_t), you can write a program to test each candidate and get the result in no time.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i think this is what you are looking for

Verifying the answer is easy, finding it in the first place, a little more work. 
 
Verification:

```
13 * 37 = 481 
481 = 8 * 60 + 1
```

Hence if you divide 13 * 37 by 60 you have remainder 1. 
 
Alternate answers: 
 
Any integer of the form (37 + 60 k) where k is any integer is also a solution.  (97, -23, etc.) 
 
To find the solution you can proceed as follows: 
Solve:

```
13 d = 1 + 60 k 
mod 13:
0 = 1 + 8k (mod 13) 
8k = -1 (mod 13) 
Add 13's until a multiple of 8 is found: 
8k = 12 or 25 or 38 or 51 or 64 .... aha a multiple of 8! 
k = 64 / 8 = 8 
Substitute k = 8 back into 13 d = 1 + 60 k 
13 d = 1 + 8 * 60 = 481 
481 /13 = 37
```

and that is the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Use the [extended Euclidean algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) to compute integers x and y such that

```
13*x+60*y=1
```

Then x is the answer you're looking for, mod 60.

Comment: what is the simplest method to calculate x because in your equation y is also unknown